# Joining 3 MySQL Tables with data comparison

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

I have 3 MySQL tables currently in my database and I was trying to work out how to join them all together and compare data between them.

The queries form part of a "Friend or Foe" system I'm currently working on as a side project in my spare time, but I cannot for the life of me work it out. I've successfully managed a 2 table join but am getting nowhere with a 3 table join.

Anyway, here is the table layout.

Table 1

```
Unique ID | Username | Password | Activity
1         | SomeUser | password | Active
2         | NewUsers | password | InActive
3         | GuestUse | password | Active
```

Table 2

```
FileID    | UploadedBy | Type | FileName | Description
1         | SomeUser   | MP3  | Demo.mp3 | Bass Guitar Riff
2         | SomeUser   | MP4  | Demo.mp4 | Some Youtube Video
```

Table 3

```
ListOwner | Friends  | Foes
SomeUser  | GuestUse | NULL
GuestUse  | SomeUser | NULL
```

All I'm trying to achieve is that the "ListOwner" can view files uploaded by users who are in his/hers "friends" list, naturally there would be a page where you could view all files uploaded, but this is more designed towards seeing uploads of people you appreciate more.

In essence I am trying to get the query to read the; "Username" from Table1, "UploadeBy" from Table2 and Everything from Table3

Example:
GuestUse logs in, the query takes this information and compares his Username against Table 3 and then shows ONLY the uploads in Table2 from those who are in his friends list.

For structure the DB has the following setup.

- Unique ID & Field ID are both INT(4)
- Username is VARCHAR(42)
- Password is VARCHAR(30)
- Activity is VARCHAR(8)
- ListOwner is VARCHAR(42) < Same as Username
- Friends & Foes are TEXT

Any help you can give would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table 2 field "uploadedby" should be the numeric user id.

```
FileID    | UploadedBy | Type | FileName | Description
1         | 1          | MP3  | Demo.mp3 | Bass Guitar Riff
2         | 1          | MP4  | Demo.mp4 | Some Youtube Video
```

You should create one table for "friend" relation and one for "foe" relation.

```
Table 3: friends
ListOwnerId | FriendId
1           | 2
1           | 3
2           | 1

Table 4: foes
ListOwnerId | FoeId
3           | 2
```

Then proceed with queries from inner to outer.

```
SELECT friendid FROM friends WHERE listowner=$loginid;
```

This will extract all friends for $loginid user.

If $someuseris is in $loginid friends list but $someuserid set $loginid as a foe, should $loginid see $someuserid files? Think of that. In the meanwhile, foes table is useless.

Now, select all files from friends:

```
SELECT * FROM files WHERE uploadedby IN (SELECT friendid FROM friends WHERE listowner=$loginid)
```

This query will give you a list of desired files.

This is done with a subquery, you can do it also with a join.

```
SELECT files.* FROM files JOIN friends ON files.uploadedby=friends.friendid WHERE friends.listowner=$loginid;
```

Comment: The foes table is used to block other users from "Friending" the user, its picked up by another query on a different page. I just wanted to keep the amount of tables down thats all.

Comment: You don't have to care about table amount. You have to care first about correct data structure.

Comment: EDIT: This works perfectly, just had to alter my db so that it would use the userID instead of username, perfect !! 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go:

```
select t1.Username,
t3.ListOwner,t3.Friends,t3.Foes,
t2.UploadedBy,t2.Type,t2.FileName,t2.Description
from Table1 t1
inner join Table3 t3 on t1.Username = t3.ListOwner
inner join Table2 t2 on t3.Friends = t2.UploadedBy
where Username = 'GuestUse';
```